# Pointer to local outside scope

Tags: c

A function returns the address of a stack variable, which will cause unintended program behavior, typically in the form of a crash.
The following function returns a stack address:

```
int init(char *device, DriverType driver)
{
    int rv = -1;

    if (autodetect) {
        void *md;
        const char *p = NULL;
        char buf[PATH_MAX];

        *device = 0;
        md = discover_media_devices();
        if (!md) {
            fprintf (stderr, "open: Failed to open \"auto\" device");
            if (*device)
                fprintf (stderr, " at %s\n", device);
            else
                fprintf (stderr, "\n");
            goto failure;
        }

        while (1) {
            p = get_associated_device(md, p, MEDIA_V4L_RADIO, NULL, NONE);
            if (!p)
                break;
            snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/dev/%s", p);
            device = &buf[0];
        }

    free_media_devices(md);
    /* out_of_scope: Variable "buf" goes out of scope */
    }

    switch (driver) {
            case DRIVER_ANY:
            case DRIVER_V4L2:
            default:
                    goto try_v4l2;
            case DRIVER_V4L1:
                    goto try_v4l1;
    }

try_v4l1:
    dev = v4l1_radio_dev_new();
    /* use_invalid: Using "device", which points to an out-of-scope variable "buf" */
    rv = dev->init (dev, device);
    ----------------------------

try_v4l2:
    dev = v4l2_radio_dev_new();
    /* use_invalid: Using "device", which points to an out-of-scope variable "buf" */
    rv = dev->init (dev, device);
    ----------------------------

failure:
    return rv;
}
```

Please help to solve this issue in code

Comment: Not so impressed by the question's code quality: indent is super-strange, and `buf` is not even shown being declared.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the function is declared with return type `int`, but it doesn't return any value.

Comment: you usually need to use `break;` inside the switch statement (it doesn't matter here because you are using gotos, but using break is usually good practice). And as @KlasLindbäck mentioned, the function should return an `integer`, but it isn't returning anything. Also, the portions `try_v...` will get executed sequentially (one then the other) unless they include a `return`. Actually I would rather have these portions defined as seperate functions and simply call them in init, since using multiple `goto`s will make your code hard to debug and follow (aka spaghetti code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You roughly have two options:

1. Allocate the char on the stack prior than calling the *init* function:

   ```
   char ch[PATH_MAX];
   init (ch, ...);
   ```
2. Allocate the char inside the function using *malloc*, and free the allocated memory outside the *init* function.

   ```
   int init(char *device, DriverType driver)
   {
        /*...*/
        device = malloc(PATH_MAX);
        /*...*/
   }


   char* p;
   init (p, ...);
   free(p);
   ```

The first option is more elegant and efficient.