# dangling pointer in c programming

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *call();


int main() {

    int *ptr, a = 5;
    ptr = call();

    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}

int * call() {
    int x = 25;
    ++x;

    return &x;
}
```

the above code outputs garbage value after printing the value of a..
but if i remove the printf("%d\n",a); statement then it outputs the value of x.
please explain...
according to concept of dangling pointer, output should be garbage value .
i'm using gcc compiler.

Comment: It looks like the value of `x`, but it is garbage.

Comment: it always prints the value of x that is 26...if i remove printf statement(printf("%d\n",a);).

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127507/912144, http://stackoverflow.com/q/19808553/912144, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8743411/912144, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4570366/912144, http://stackoverflow.com/q/15903499/912144 and many others.

Answer (score 1):

What actually happened is call to the first printf overwrote the location where ptr is pointing.

The reason is you returned a pointer to a variable that then went out of scope.

This is undefined behavior.

Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Applying `*` operator to an *indeterminate pointer* (pointing anywhere) invokes undefined behavior. You may get anything. You are getting `26` possibly because after the call of `call`, `26` is stored in execution stack. `*ptr` takes that value from the stack.